# How to setup Nginix Docker Reverse proxy

Tags: azure, docker, nginx

I am trying to use Nginix reverse proxy container for my web application(another docker container) which runs on non standard port ,

unfortunately I cannot edit my web application container as its developed by some vendor , so I have a plain request that I need to setup nginx as frontend with 80/443 and forward all requests to 10.0.0.0:10101(web app container).

I had tried jwilder/nginx proxy and default docker nginx container not able to get the right configurtaion .any lead would be great.

At the moment I haven't shared any conf files , I can share it on demand. here is the environment details

```
OS - Ubuntu
Azure
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `proxy_pass` nginx feature

Assuming you have both containers linked and the web app container's name is `webapp` use this configuration on `nginx` container

```
  upstream backend {
    server webapp:10101;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass   http://backend;
    }
  }
```

NOTE: please note that I am skipping some configurations as this is just an example

Put the configuration in `nginx.conf` file and then deploy the container like this

```
docker run -d -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -p 80:80 nginx
```

Then you'll be able to access your webapp on http://locahost

Comment: Hi Hernan , I had tried this and am sure am missing something , sorry am being so naive here , this is what I had done 
1. I have Azure machine with Public IP 
2. Installed docker container from vendor where it runs on non standard port 
3. installed the Nginix container with above conf
4. Linked both containers with following command in bridge network 
docker network connect dinesh-test:dinesh nginx-proxy fermant
5. tried browsing the url but no luck

Comment: I think I am making the mistake in linking the container with nginx container I use following command,
docker run -d --name dinesh -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --link=vigilant_liskov --net nginx-pr
oxy dineshnginx1

Comment: I used `webapp` as an example but this should be the container name, try `server vigilant_liskov:10101;` or check the `/etc/hosts` file inside the nginx container ;-)

Comment: thanks ! I am still finding it difficult to link the containers , I will let you know how this goes. thanks again for your time

Comment: @Dinesh were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing similar problem with Azure multi containers deployment.